# Can't connect to the internet after removing VPN

Tags: network, macos, vpn, proxy, router

I installed the **Star VPN application** from the App Store and connected to **United States VPN**. Everything was working fine until I removed the application. I'm able to access some Bigger or famous sites such as Google, Facebook, Youtube, Stack Exchange, etc. but I can't access other websites such as w3schools.com, kibase.com, etc. Not only it affected my Macbook, but other devices connected to the same router are not able to access these websites. Only after installing the Star VPN back on Macbook, these sites are accessible but only from that Mac which again won't load on even closing the VPN.

**Symptoms that I noticed after uninstalling Star VPN:**

- Can't Open small websites
- Location Unavailable on Google
- Affected Every device connected to the same router

**Things I Tried:**

- Reset my router
- Doubled checked the IPv4 and DNS settings(using a static IP address and 8.8.4.4, 8.8.8.8 DNS)
- Checked Browser Proxies(none used)

I still can't access some websites from the same router. Please help. I'm using macOS Sierra version 10.12.5.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Have you contacted Star VPN support for help?

Comment: I sent an email about the same and got a reply just now stating - Their application(Star VPN) does not affects the router but changes only the network settings of the device on which it is installed(Macbook Pro here) @IconDaemon